# VB6.SetItemData(combobox, i, rd.Fields("XXX").Value)

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb.net-2010, vb6-migration

I am converting VB6 to VB.NET using VS2010

When I was converting the code, I found something that I don't understand the meaning of what the code is doing and getting and how to convert it well.

```
i = 0

While Not rd.EOF

        cobTmp.Items.Insert(i, rd.Fields("d").Value)
        VB6.SetItemData(cobTmp, i, rd.Fields("r").Value)
        If rd.Fields("r").Value = "1234" Then
            intloc1234 = i
        End If
        rd.MoveNext()
        Debug.Print(VB6.TabLayout(VB6.GetItemData(cobTmp, i), VB6.GetItemString(cobTmp, i)))
        i = i + 1
    End While
```

How can I handle this code well and for this line:

```
Debug.Print(VB6.TabLayout(VB6.GetItemData(cobTmp, i), VB6.GetItemString(cobTmp, i)))
```

Can I use `cobTmp.item(i)` to replace `VB6.GetItemData(cobTmp, i)`?

How about `VB6.TabLayout`??

I know these can be ignored, but I want to do it better.

Comment: Sorry - I really am finding it very hard to understand the question.

Comment: i am converting code from VB6 to VB.NET. above coding is come from VB6 and it makes warming in VS2010 . and i want to solve the code which is started with VB6.xxxxx. =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `GetItemData`, according to [Microsoft Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compatibility.vb6.support.getitemdata.aspx):

> In Visual Basic 6.0, the ItemData property for a ListBox or ComboBox control could be set at design time in the Properties window to associate an Integer with a ListBox or ComboBox item. In Visual Basic 2010, the ItemData property no longer exists; the GetItemData and SetItemData methods can be used to emulate the behavior of ItemData.

Regarding `TabLayout`, according to this [Microsoft Support Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compatibility.vb6.support.tablayout.aspx):

> In Visual Basic 6.0, the Debug.Print method had an outputlist parameter that specified how output was formatted in the Immediate window. This function is used by the upgrade tools to translate the outputlist parameter into a string for display in the Immediate window.

Comment: +1 We could also link to the VB6 documentation on [`ItemData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235132(v=vs.60).aspx). But if the `ItemData` and `TabLayout` is really only used in a `Debug.Print` statement, just delete the code and move on to something else :) Debug.Print is just a logging statement.

Comment: Thank you so much, i am trying to move on to others=]